# Save data into database, based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

I have created two forms that display on radio button selection. I also created two different tables in my database for the different radio button selection.

I want to store the different forms to the different tables based on the radio button selection. On selection of "Private User", I want the data inputted on the form to store to tbl_users and on selection of "Professional Agent",I want the data inputted on the form to store to tbl_agents.

I have tried doing this, but the data isn't storing to the table.

Anybody know how to do this?

Regards, Asvp

Here's my code:

```js
 

 function ShowHideDiv() {
            
            var chkYes1 = document.getElementById("chkYes1");
            var dvtext1 = document.getElementById("dvtext1");
            var dvtext13 = document.getElementById("dvtext13");
            var dvtext12 = document.getElementById("dvtext12");
            var dvtext11 = document.getElementById("dvtext11");
            var dvtext10 = document.getElementById("dvtext10");
            var dvtext9 = document.getElementById("dvtext9");
            var chkYes2 = document.getElementById("chkYes2");
            var dvtext8 = document.getElementById("dvtext8");
            var dvtext7 = document.getElementById("dvtext7");
            var dvtext5 = document.getElementById("dvtext5");
            var dvtext4 = document.getElementById("dvtext4");
            var dvtext3 = document.getElementById("dvtext3");
            var dvtext2 = document.getElementById("dvtext2");
            var button = document.getElementById("button");
            dvtext1.style.display = chkYes1.checked||chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvtext9.style.display = chkYes1.checked||chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvtext10.style.display = chkYes1.checked||chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvtext11.style.display = chkYes1.checked||chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvtext12.style.display = chkYes1.checked||chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvtext13.style.display = chkYes1.checked||chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";


            dvtext2.style.display = chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvtext3.style.display = chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvtext4.style.display = chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvtext5.style.display = chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvtext7.style.display = chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
            dvtext8.style.display = chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";

            btn1.style.display = chkYes1.checked ? "block" : "none";
            btn2.style.display = chkYes2.checked ? "block" : "none";
        }
```

```html
<?php

require('db.php');
// If form submitted, insert values into the database.
if (isset($_REQUEST['first_name'])){
 $first_name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['first_name']); // removes backslashes
 $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$first_name); //escapes special characters in a string
 $last_name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['last_name']);
 $email = stripslashes($_REQUEST['email']);
 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$email);
 $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
 $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$password);
 $phone = stripslashes($_REQUEST['phone']);
 $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$phone);

    $query = "INSERT into `tbl_users` (first_name, last_name, email, password, phone) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name', '$email', '".md5($password)."', '$phone')";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($result){
        echo "<div class='form'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
    }
}else{
   ?>

<form name="create" action="" method="post">
   
  
            <label for="chkYes1">
                <input type="radio" id="chkYes1" name="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
                Private User
            </label>
            <br>
            <label for="chkYes2">
                <input type="radio" id="chkYes2" name="chk" onclick="ShowHideDiv() " checked="checked" />
                Professional Agent
            </label>
            <br>

            <br>
            <div id="dvtext1" style="display: none" class="lgntxt">
               First Name *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="first_name" required />
            </div>

            <br>
            <div id="dvtext9" style="display: none" class="lgntxt">
               Last Name *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="last_name" required />
            </div>

            <br>
            <div id="dvtext10" style="display: none" class="lgntxt">
               Email Address *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="email" required />
            </div>

            <br>
            <div id="dvtext11" style="display: none" class="lgntxt">
               Password *
                <br>
                <input type="password" id="txtBox" name="password" required />
            </div>

            <br>
            <div id="dvtext12" style="display: none" class="lgntxt">
              Repeat password *
                <br>
                <input type="password" id="txtBox" />
            </div>
       
            
            <br>
            <div id="dvtext13" style="display: none" class="lgntxt">
               Phone Number *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="phone" required />
            </div>



            <br>
            <div id="dvtext2" class="lgntxt" style="display: none">
               Agency Name *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="aname"  />
            </div>

            <br>
            <div id="dvtext3" class="lgntxt" style="display: none">
              Office Address *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="oadd"  />
            </div>

             <br>
            <div id="dvtext4" class="lgntxt" style="display: none">
              City *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="city"  />
            </div>

            <br>
            <div id="dvtext5" class="lgntxt" style="display: none">
               Zip Code *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="zip"  />
            </div>
<br>
            <div id="dvtext7" class="lgntxt" style="display: none">
               Office Phone Number *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="ophn" />
            </div> 

            <br>
            <div id="dvtext8" class="lgntxt" style="display: none">
               Office Email Address *
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="oemail"  />
            </div> 




            <!--  <button style="display: none" id="btn1" class="btn third" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">CONTINUE</button> -->
       <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" style="display: none" id="btn1" class="btn third" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Print the $query before you execute it.  Is it complete?  Does it run on the database if you try it manually?  Do the same for $_REQUEST, what do you receive?

Comment: @Nic3500, I have tried it, but when I click on the submit button, the page loads and goes blank, without saving any entry

Comment: Using request is a terrible idea. Use `$_POST`

Comment: If you get a blank page, that means your PHP did not run, check your error logs.

Comment: @Nic3500 my error log is clean, I just checked

Comment: The usual way of doing this is: 1) create a form, method="POST", action="somepage.php".  When pressing the submit button, the selected radio button is sent to the action page via the $_POST array.  2) in the action page (somepage.php), process the value from $_POST, execute whatever logic you need.  3) in somepage.php, use prepared statements and bound variables to prevent SQL injection.  Example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp the whole section.

Comment: 1) I tried your code, except executing the query of course, and it did create a query.  Now is that query valid?  I do not know.  Print your query, run is directly on the database and see.  2) Replace $_REQUEST by $_POST.  3) For professional user, there is no register button.